ReactJS have old field values in Update
I am trying to update Book in Update page, and am not sure how to use old values instead of all inputs being cleared, and am not sure where to look at for it. Below is my form in Update page
return (
    <div className='form'>
        <h1>Update book</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder='title' onChange={handleChange} name='title'></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder='description' onChange={handleChange} name='description'></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder='cover' onChange={handleChange} name='cover'></input>
        <input type="number" placeholder='price' onChange={handleChange} name='price'></input>
        <button className="formButton" onClick={handleClick}>Update book</button>
    </div>

and other things in class like hook UseState() which uses all empty values (am not sure if i should and how to populate with old values)
import React from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useNavigate,useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Update = () => {

    const[book,setBook]=useState({
        title:"",
        description:"",
        cover:"",
        price: null
    })

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location=useLocation()

    const bookId=location.pathname.split("/")[2]

    const handleChange =(e)=>{
        setBook(prev=>({...prev, [e.target.name]:e.target.value}))
        console.log(e.target.name)
    }

    const handleClick = async e =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        try{
            await axios.put("http://localhost:8001/books/"+bookId,book)
            navigate("/")
            console.log(book.title)
        }catch(err){

In the form for updating i have placed key={book.ID} and then tried to use value {book.title},{book.description} etc., but nothing is showing. Would be very grateful if someone knows how that can be fixed.Thank you for reading.(i am trying to have inputs filled with old values instead of being empty)


Are you saying that when you type in your input fields the characters aren't showing up on the screen? This should definitely work if you put eg value={book.title} in your JSX.       

Thank you for the comment. When i go to page Update.js i am unable to see old field values since all input fields are empty. (i am looking how to replace empty fields because i want to see if the values for certain fields should be updated in the first place)

I'm not sure what you mean by old field values - do you mean populating the form with the existing values for the book?

Yes, existing values should be viewed instead of empty fields. sorry for not being clear

You need to do something to get the book data initially and use it to set the book state. This is not tested because I don't have access to the back end you are using, but something like this.
Add the useEffect hook to your imports:
import { useEffect } from 'react'

Then use it to issue a get request to the back end (with the other functions above your return statement):
const getBook = async () => {
  try {
    return await axios.get("http://localhost:8001/books/" + bookId)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error! ',err)
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  const currbook = getBook();
  // maybe you need to do something here to format the data
  setBook(currbook);
}, [])

The [] as the second parameter to the useEffect hook means this will only run once after the initial render.
Then don't forget to put the resulting values of the book into your JSX
  <input type="text" placeholder='title' onChange={handleChange} name='title' value={book.title} />
  <input type="text" placeholder='description' onChange={handleChange} name='description' value={book.description} />
  <input type="text" placeholder='cover' onChange={handleChange} name='cover' value={book.cover} />
  <input type="number" placeholder='price' onChange={handleChange} name='price' value={book.price} />


Thank you for reading and the response. I tried this `const[book,setBook]=useState({
    book: axios.get("http://localhost:8001/books/"+bookId)
},[])` to use in my Update.js, but it doesn't work for some reason, and will need to see why. On the server i have following code `app.get("/books/:id",(req,res)=>{
const bookId=req.params.id;
const q="SELECT title,description,cover,price where id=?"
db.query(q,[bookId],(err,data)=>{
    return res.json("Book has been retrieved")
})

})`Thank you for responding.

Yep, you need to issue that get request from the useEffect hook, not the useState hook. That's the bit in my second code snippet above

All you have to do is connect each of the book's keys with the input's value properties.
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

const INITIAL_FORM = { // initialize a default form values
    title: '',
    description: '',
    cover: '',
    price: null,
}

const Update = () => {
    const [book, setBook] = useState(INITIAL_FORM)
    const { bookId } = useParams() // use :bookId param from router

    const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        setBook((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            const request = await axios.put('http://localhost:8001/books/' + bookId, book)

            if (![200, 201].includes(request.status)) return

            // handle after success...
            // e.g. navigate to somewhere else...
        } catch (err) {
            // handle error
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // get the initial book data from the server using the bookId
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8001/books/' + bookId)
                setBook(data)
            } catch (err) {
                // handle error
            }
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="form">
            <h1>Update book</h1>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="title"
                value={book.title} // book's title
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="title"
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="description"
                value={book.description} // book's description
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="description"
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="cover"
                value={book.cover} // book's cover
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="cover"
            />
            <input
                type="number"
                placeholder="price"
                value={book.price || ''} // book's price
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="price"
            />
            <button
                className="formButton"
                onClick={handleSubmit}
            >
                Update book
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Update

Additionally:

You could use react's useParams() to get the bookId from the URL by implementing this in the router:

{
   path: '/book-form-update/:bookId',
   element: <Update />,
}


Thank you for reading and the response. I tried this `const[book,setBook]=useState({
    book: axios.get("http://localhost:8001/books/"+bookId)
},[])` to use in my Update.js, but it doesn't work for some reason, and will need to see why. On the server file index.js i have following code `app.get("/books/:id",(req,res)=>{
const bookId=req.params.id;
const q="SELECT title,description,cover,price where id=?"
db.query(q,[bookId],(err,data)=>{
    return res.json("Book has been retrieved")
})

})` Thank you for response.

@slomil call the axios.get() outside useState initialization. Your useState form is incorrect like that. On the other hand, you will call other book's props using book.book.title for example. Don't make it more complicated.
